# Synchronized methods within AsyncTasks

Tags: android, android-asynctask, synchronized

My application is collecting data from sensors and I have the user manually save labels. Whenever the user touches a button to save a label, I run an AsyncTask and inside the doInBackground method, I'm calling a synchronized method whose unique purpose is to save the information in a file. The method is part of a helper library so I access it through as a static method, so it is a synchronized static method. I need the labeling to saved in the order it was entered. However, I noticed that sometimes the labels are saved in a different order which tells me that the synchronized method might not be working as expected

1. Is there any restriction for synchronized methods within AsyncTasks?
2. Is there any better way to accomplish this? I mean, keep saving the data in a background thread but ensuring that if we have multiple, I execute them in the order they arrived?

The code looks a little like this:

```
public class FileUtil {
    public static synchronized void saveActivityDataToFile() throws IOException{
       //Saving file code
    }
}

//This asynctask is called everytime the user touches the button
private class SaveDataInBackground extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

    public SaveDataInBackground(){
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(String... lists) {
        try {
            //I expect this to run on its own thread but synchronously if this asynctask is called multiple times withing a short interval of time
            FileUtil.saveActivityDataToFile();
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG,"Error while saving activity: " + e.getMessage());  
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no restrictions against it, however you could cause starvation or deadlock.  You should always ensure synchronized methods finish quickly, but especially so in an AsyncTask.

Comment: @user1055395 This is how I call the asynctask. 
`SaveDataInBackground backgroundSave = new SaveDataInBackground(this);
backgroundSave.execute(timestamp, label);`

Comment: So, @GabeSechan do you think saving the file this way is not a good idea? For this particular case im simply saving a label which shouldn't be longer than let's say 50 characters. However, I plan to use this same approach for much bigger files.

Comment: No, its perfectly fine to call a synchronized function on a AsyncTask so long as no synchronized function on that object would hold the lock for an unreasonable time.  Saving a file is a perfectly reasonable amount of time to hold it.  I'd worry about anything that could take more than a few seconds, but not anything that takes milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There are **no** any restrictions for synchronized methods in `AsyncTasks`

Btw synchronized is not about order, its about **blocking** part of code for only one thread in time. So there can be situation:

Task 1 started

Task 2 started

Task 2 write and finish

Task 1 write and finish

2. You could use `Thread` instead of `AsyncTask`. And then use `ThreadPoolExecutor` with only one thread or use `thread.join()`

But better to use `RxJava2` or `Kotlin Coroutines` for such things

Comment: I understand that synchronized its about blocking, but what happens with any other thread that tries to access? Let's say, right after task 1 started and blocked, task 2 and task 3 started in that order. What happens? does task 2 and 3 simply finishes or they wait until task 1 releases and then when released, task 2 goes before task 3?

Comment: @Roger, tasks 2 & 3 waits until task1 release part of code and should resume executing in same order

Comment: @Roger if you start your AsyncTask using execute() then all requests run in queue.